# How can I display the duration of the video on IE?

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, video, video.js, display

Using video.js, I'm trying to display the duration time of the video when it's playing. On the google chrome, it displays it fine, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to display it on IE using the same source. Right now it's showing the remaining time instead of the duration.

**On Chrome**
[image]

**On IE**
[image]

Current Source:

```html
<video id="myVideo" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-tech" 
       width="100%" height="auto" controls="" preload="auto" 
       data-setup="{ "aspectRatio" : "1024:634", 
                     "playbackRates" : [0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.5, 1.75, 2]}" 
       controlslist="nodownload" autoplay="">
 <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm"> 
</video>
```

Please anyone let me know if you know how.
Thank you.

Comment: According to [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/browsers/default.asp) only 4.1 % users were still using IE/Edge, so I guess don't worry about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<head>
  <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/6.6.3/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- If you'd like to support IE8 -->
  <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/1.1.2/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <video id="my-video" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264"
  poster="MY_VIDEO_POSTER.jpg" data-setup="{}">
    <source src="MY_VIDEO.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
    <source src="MY_VIDEO.webm" type='video/webm'>
    <p class="vjs-no-js">
      To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
      <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
    </p>
  </video>

  <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/6.6.3/video.js"></script>
</body>


check the below link 
--------------------
https://docs.videojs.com/docs/guides/options.html
```

Comment: My source was missing video-js.css and video.js. Adding them, now I have exact same display on both chrome and ie. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The method I use is this:

```html
 <!--   Force "current-time / duration" to appear on the control-bar: -->
 <!--   See:    https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/2507  -->
 <style>
  .video-js   .vjs-current-time { display: block; }
  .video-js   .vjs-time-divider { display: block; }
  .video-js   .vjs-duration { display: block; }
  .video-js   .vjs-remaining-time { display: none; }
 </style>
```

This appears to work fine on IE. (I use videojs v5.11.9, rather than v6.6.3)

An additional comment, regarding Edge-browser:

Last time I tested Edge, I found that it complains if you have the
type attribute on a Webm.  i.e. keep then remove the expected 
    type="video/webm"
from your second 'source' and put the webm source first, and
I think you'll experience their bug.  In other words, Edge won't
use a Webm file, if you have the type="video/webm" in the source-tag.

EDIT:  One other thing...I too use the choice of faster playback rates,
but I never understood their not-an-integer example values, so I prefer:
    data-setup='{ "playbackRates": [1, 2, 3, 4] }'

Cheers...

Dave

Comment: I added the style part of your suggestion and couple of js and css file in my source, it works fine now. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Glad I could help.  ( Video.js is a VERY cool product, so this is my way of supporting/giving-back to it.  Ditto for GitHub! )